# use of undeclared identifier 'connect'

Tags: qt, identifier, qt-connection

I'm trying to write a simple downloader in qt. It's based on this example: http://www.ggkf.com/qt/qnetworkrequest-to-download-an-image

downloader.cpp:

```
void Downloader::GetImage( QString _url, QNetworkAccessManager *qnam ) {
    connect( qnam, SIGNAL( finished( QNetworkReply *) ), this, SLOT( replyFinished(   QNetworkReply * ) ) );

    QUrl url = QUrl( _url );
    QNetworkRequest request( url );

    qnam->get( request );
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
/Users/name/ssl/downloader.cpp:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'connect'
connect( qnam, SIGNAL( finished( QNetworkReply *) ), this, SLOT( replyFinished( QNetworkReply * ) ) );
```

Can anyone of you explain to me this error?

Comment: Are you missing a header file inclusion?

Comment: Downloader does probably not inherit from QObject? It must.

Comment: Thanks you two. It was the missing inheritance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

please ensure Downloader does inherit from QObject.

```
class Downloader : public QObject{

}
```

Comment: @LorenzMeyer, yes, but this is a common issue faced by Qt newbies, and thus deserves an answer on its own, even if it was given in the comment.

Comment: Just because it's old, doesn't (always) make it incorrect -- it's the first answer that pops up on google, and has immediately given me the correct answer.